# Return value in list 1 based upon index of max value in list 2

Tags: python

I am defining a function `largest_value` that takes three list arguments: `type_list`, `value_list` and a variable called `label` which will show us what value variable was passed to the function.

The function should find the car type with the largest value and print the type of car together with the highest value and the label for that value.

For example,

```
largest_value(['Car1', 'Car2', 'Car3'], [30, 40, 25], 'MPG')
```

should print:

```
Car2 has the most MPG of 40.
```

Comment: Use `max()` to find the largest value, then use `value_list.index()` to find its position.  Now you have all three things that you need to print the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bundle up the values of `value_list` and `type_list` using `zip`, and then find the max (the default ordering of tuples is to order by the first item, then the second and so on):

```py
def largest_value(type_list, value_list, label):
    bundled = zip(value_list, type_list)
    largest_value, largest_type = max(bundled)
    print(f'{largest_type} has the most {label} of {largest_value}')
```

( You can merge the first two lines in the function into one line: `largest_value, largest_type = max(zip(value_list, type_list))`)
**Edit:** changed the order of the `zip` to avoid the use of a custome key -- thanks @mkrieger1

Comment: When using `zip(value_list, type_list)` instead, no `key` argument is needed.